# confirm password validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have an html file and I am trying to check two password field ( Password & conform Password), I have to use this particular form I can't use any sample, I have looked at examples here and I came a cross a working example and I tried to get it work but it's not working so far, i am new to this so please be patient with me on this

```
<div id="register" class="animate form">
 <form action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 
 <h1> Sign up </h1> 
 <p> 
 <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
 <input id="usernamesignup" class="username" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690">
 <span class="check"  ></span> 
 </p>
 <p> 
 <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e"> Your email</label>
 <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"> 
 </p>
 <p> 
 <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
 <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO">
 </p>
 <p> 
 <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
  <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" onkeyup="checkPasswordMatch(); placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO">
  </p>
  <p class="signin button"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Sign up"> 
  </p>
  <p class="change_link">  
Already a member ?
  <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
</p>
</form>
```

I have added this function to the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkPasswordMatch() {
    var password = $("#passwordsignup").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#passwordsignup_confirm").val();

    if (password != confirmPassword)
        $("#register").html("Passwords do not match!");
    else
        $("#register").html("Passwords match.");
}
</script>
```

according to the example it should work but obviously I am doing something wrong here, appreciate your help.

Comment: You should be doing this kind of validation on the server as well, FYI.

Comment: @tymeJV There's no bad in doing a preliminary check in the user's browser.

Comment: #register is the div that contains your whole form where you are entering the password...I would avoid to wipe it with your error message. Moreover **you did forget a quote**: onkeyup="checkPasswordMatch();"

Comment: Have you verified that your variables in the javascript are being set correctly?

Comment: So exactly what errors are you receiving?

Comment: I think so,it should be like this  `<input type="submit" value="Sign up" onClientClick="checkPasswordMatch();">`

Comment: Instead on keyup, do validation on blur of the confirm password field. It will be the better option. because if u enter the first lettter the function will trigger and register div will be replaced by your text.

Comment: Thanks for your replys @Raj, you mean using <lable> lines instead of <input> lines?and also I am not sure about where should I put this function in the code, at the moment it's just before the form.

Answer (score 1):

This line is messed up.

```
 onkeyup="checkPasswordMatch(); placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO">
```

Your double quotes are not matched.

Answer (score 1):

In the code you posted, you are missing an `"` after `onkeyup="checkPasswordMatch();`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I added " but still not working

Comment: check the values, as suggested in a comment to your question. This can be done by adding `console.log( password ); console.log( confirmPassword' );` after you've assigned the values in javascript  - before the "if" condition. the values will show up in your browser's console.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="register" class="animate form">
 <form action="mysuperscript.php" autocomplete="on"> 
 <h1> Sign up </h1> 
 <p> 
 <label for="usernamesignup" class="uname" data-icon="u">Your username</label>
 <input id="usernamesignup" class="username" name="usernamesignup" required="required" type="text" placeholder="mysuperusername690">
 <span class="check"  ></span> 
 </p>
 <p> 
 <label for="emailsignup" class="youmail" data-icon="e"> Your email</label>
 <input id="emailsignup" name="emailsignup" required="required" type="email" placeholder="mysupermail@mail.com"> 
 </p>
 <p> 
 <label for="passwordsignup" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Your password </label>
 <input id="passwordsignup" name="passwordsignup" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO">
 </p>
 <p> 
 <label for="passwordsignup_confirm" class="youpasswd" data-icon="p">Please confirm your password </label>
  <input id="passwordsignup_confirm" name="passwordsignup_confirm" required="required" type="password" placeholder="eg. X8df!90EO">
  </p>
  <div id="msg"></div>
  <p class="signin button"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Sign up"> 
  </p>
  <p class="change_link">  
Already a member ?
  <a href="#tologin" class="to_register"> Go and log in </a>
</p>
</body>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#passwordsignup_confirm").keyup(function(){
    var password = $("#passwordsignup").val();
    var confirmPassword = $("#passwordsignup_confirm").val();

    if (password !== confirmPassword){
        $("#msg").html("Passwords do not match!");
    }else{
        $("#msg").html("Passwords match.");
    }
});
});

</script>
</html>
```

Check the above code!!

Comment: Thanks for your replys again @Raj, do I need to verified thoes variables in the another javascript? I have used your code in my html file, still not getting any message in the browser

Comment: chk next to password field.. i displayed the message in msg div. place it where you want

Comment: Hi @Raj, I spend times on it still not working, its bigger script that I paste here, can I send you the whole script and have a look at it maybe I put you code in the wrong place, please tell me if I am asking too much, I'll understand.